# trying to setup password recovery in nodejs using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer, mern

tried to setup a password recovery in my nodejs project using nodemailer.I have got 'no recipients defined' error. how to fix the code?.

here is my code:

```
app.post('/forgotpass', (req, res, next)=> {
    let recoveryPassword = '';
   async.waterfall([
        (done) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, (err , buf) => {
                let token = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, token);
            });
        },
        (token, done) => {
            User.findOne({username : req.body.username})
                .then(user => {
                    if(!user) {
                        console.log("user does not exists");
                        return res.redirect('/forgotpass');
                    }

                    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 1800000; //   1/2 hours

                    user.save(err => {
                        done(err, token, user);
                    });
                });

        },
        (token, user) => {
            let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                            port: 465,
                            auth: {
                                user: 'test@gmail.com',
                                pass: 'testpass'
                            }
            });

            let mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from : 'Ghulam Abbas myapkforest@gmail.com',
                subject : 'Recovery Email from Auth Project',
                text : 'Please click the following link to recover your passoword: \n\n'+
                        'http://'+ req.headers.host +'/reset/'+token+'\n\n'+
                        'If you did not request this, please ignore this email.'
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, err=> {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/forgotpass');
            });
                        
        }

    ], err => {
        if(err) res.redirect('/forgotpass');
                if (err )console.log(err);
    });
});
```

and here is the error I got :

```
Error: No recipients defined
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:995:34)
at SMTPConnection.send (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
at sendMessage (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)
at C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1537:9)
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:550:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\JITHENDRA\Desktop\project\node\Secrets-Starting-Code\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)  {
    code: 'EENVELOPE',
    command: 'API'
      }
```

that's the error I have got.please fix the code
I just want the node mailer to send the mail after verifying the user exists or not

Comment: The line `from : 'Ghulam Abbas myapkforest@gmail.com'` is malformed. It should have brackets around the email, like this: `'Ghulam Abbas <myapkforest@gmail.com>'`.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you aren't passing a `mailOptions.to` value, so the `user.email` value is empty or not a valid email address. If you utilize `async/await` you can write the code more concisely and avoid using `async.waterfall` to make it easier to debug. There are a few changes/typos noted below -

```
// define transport here, outside the handler
const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
      user: 'test@gmail.com',
      pass: 'testpass'
  }
});

// use async function as the handler
app.post('/forgotpass', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({username : req.body.username});
  
    if (!user) {
      console.log("user does not exists");
      return res.redirect('/forgotpass');
    }
    // make sure you have a valid email here
    console.log(`Sending email to ${user.email}`);
  
    // get token here once we have a valid user
    const token = crypto.randomBytes(20);
  
    // update the user with the token
    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 1800000; //   1/2 hours
    await user.save();
  
    // send the email
    await smtpTransport.sendMail({
      to: user.email,
      from : 'Ghulam Abbas <myapkforest@gmail.com>', // <-- wrap email address in <>
      subject : 'Recovery Email from Auth Project',
      text : 'Please click the following link to recover your passoword: \n\n'+ // <-- typo: "passoword" should be "password"
      'http://'+ req.headers.host +'/reset/'+token+'\n\n'+ // <-- use HTTPS!
      'If you did not request this, please ignore this email.'
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // catch all exceptions here...
    console.log(err);
  }

  // everything redirects to the GET handler for forgotpass
  return res.redirect('/forgotpass');
});
```